# How to add an object to a list inside another object C#?

Tags: c#, list, oop, blazor, blazor-editform

***My application should be based upon the following***:

The user creates a Company, inside the Company is a list of boards. The user then creates a Board which is added to the list of boards inside the Company. Like a one to many relationship.

***My Question***:

I'm not sure how to implement this?

This is what I currently have. (Not working due to freezing after pressing submit on the Create_Board).

##### Company.cs

```cs
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Founded { get; set; }

        public List<Board> Boards { get; set; }

        public Company()
        {
        }

        public Company(string name, DateTime founded)
        {
            Name = name;
            Founded = founded;
            Boards = new List<Board>();
        }
    }
```

##### Create_Company.razor

```cs
@page "/create_company"

@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject HttpClient Http

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary oi oi-arrow-left" @onclick="GoToReadCompany"></button>
    <h3 class="text-center">Create Company</h3>
</div>

<hr />

<hr />

<EditForm Model="Company" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" @bind-Value="Company.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Company.Name)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="CompanyFounded" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Founded</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputDate id="CompanyFounded" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Company.Founded" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Company.Founded)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private void GoToReadCompany()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/read_companies");
    }

    private Company Company { get; set; } = new Company("", new DateTime());

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("VALID SUBMIT!");

            Company newCompany = new Company(Company.Name, Company.Founded);

            var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Companies", newCompany);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            Navigation.NavigateTo("/read_companies");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred for POST company");
        }
    }
}
```

##### Board.cs

```cs
public class Board
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [ValidateComplexType]
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

        public Board()
        {
        }

        public Board(string name, string description, Company company)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            Company = company;
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>();
        }
    }
```

##### Create_Board.razor

```cs
@page "/create_board"

@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject HttpClient Http

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary oi oi-arrow-left" @onclick="GoToHome"></button>
    <h3 class="text-center">Create Board</h3>
</div>

<hr />

<EditForm Model="Board" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Company" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <InputSelect id="Company" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Board.Company">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Company</option>
                    @foreach (var company in Companies)
                    {
                        <option value="@company">@company.Name</option>
                    }
                </InputSelect>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Board.Company)" />
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" @bind-Value="Board.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Board.Name)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" @bind-Value="Board.Description" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Board.Description)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

        @code {
            private void GoToHome()
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/");
            }

            private Board Board { get; set; } = new Board("","", new Company());

            private List<Company> Companies = new List<Company>();

            protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
            {
                try
                {
                    Companies = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Company>>("api/Companies");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred for GET companies");
                }
            }

            private async void HandleValidSubmit()
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("VALID SUBMIT!");

                    Board newBoard = new Board(Board.Name, Board.Description, Board.Company);

                    var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Boards", newBoard);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    Navigation.NavigateTo($"/");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred for POST board");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So.. what does "freezing after submit" mean?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it has. Basically I managed to create both objects correctly but I was calling the wrong constructors and the relationship they had with each other was wrong. At the moment I believe I've correctly created the relationship now, however similarly to last time when I fill in the EditForm for the Create_Board and hit submit nothing happens, no exception, no printing in the console of "VALID SUBMIT!" nothing.

Comment: Have you turned off all the validation ?

Comment: Alternatively, wire up an OnInvalidSubmit event/handler so you can see that there's hopefully *something* happening when you click...

Comment: If I remove the <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator /> and the <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Board.Company)" /> the console prints the "VALID SUBMIT" however I 
 then receive a 400 post exception and then the console prints "Exception occurred for POST board" If this helps?

Comment: So, validation is preventing anything happening, and when you remove validation, something is invalid. One of the problems here is your debugging isn't very involved, and your error messages aren't very useful.. `catch(Exception) { print("there was an error")` doesn't tell you anything about the error - it would genuinely be better off not being there at all. Remove the try/catch words or set a breakpoint in the catch, and inspect the error that occurred, or you write `catch(Exception ex){ ...` and you dig data out of the `ex` and put it in the message

Comment: Personally, I would turn on "break when thrown" in the **debug menu>windows>exception settings>(put a check next to CLR)**, and when an error occurs and VS stops, look really closely into the error itself.

Comment: If you don't know what a breakpoint is, find out with a bit of experimentation in a simpler program: write a basic console program (make a new project to get a hello world), put the cursor on the Hello World line, press F9 so it goes red, run the app. Use F10 and F11 to step one instruction at a time (move the yellow bar; F11 goes into methods, F10 runs them without going into them) and point to variables with your mouse or use the Locals window to inspect the values of variables to determine if data is flowing round your app in the right way

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);` returns: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). If that is any help?

Comment: Not much; you need to find out why the request fails. Can you successfully call the API (companies controller, [HttpPost] decorated method) from a tool like Insomnia (a tool that sends test requests to APIs) ?

Comment: I have used swagger to check and both of the HttpPost in Company and Board work as they should. (Code 200)

Comment: So we could do with taking a look at what is being sent by the browser. Open the dev tools (F12) and look in the network tab while you post to /api/Companies/ etc - you can click the request and see the json sent. on the right. If it looks wonky, you can place a breakpoint in the code within the try, pause the submit and look at the data being formed; is something missing etc

Comment: An observation, probably unwelcome, but I'll make it anyway:  you have posted at least one more question on the project.  You appear to be building a lot of your application logic into your data layer - relationships between objects - and building application logic into your UI layer - `Http.PostAsJsonAsync` in your components.  Take a step back and think about your overall design.

Comment: Agree, though I do feel that' appreciation for separation of concerns is something that comes in time. In a process of "make it, make it work, make it right, make it fast", we're on step 2.. :)

Comment: I had an error from using `@company` as a value so I changed this to `@company.Id` and checked the network preview. It now says that: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Boards_Companies_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in database "******", table "dbo.Companies", column 'Id'.